# How to create indexed view of children count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, indexed-view

I am trying to take a table with a parent child relationship and get the number of children. I would like to create an indexed view of the number of children by utilizing `COUNT_BIG(*)`.

The problem is that in my index view I don't want to eliminate the entities who have no children, instead I want the `Count` to be 0 for those.

Given

```
> Id | Entity | Parent
> -: | :----- | :-----
>  1 | A      | null  
>  2 | AA     | A     
>  3 | AB     | A     
>  4 | ABA    | AB    
>  5 | ABB    | AB    
>  6 | AAA    | AA    
>  7 | AAB    | AA    
>  8 | AAC    | AA
```

I want to create an indexed view that returns

```
> Entity | Count
> :----- | ----:
> A      |     2
> AA     |     3
> AB     |     2
> ABA    |     0
> ABB    |     0
> AAA    |     0
> AAB    |     0
> AAC    |     0
```

Here is my SQL that works, but using a LEFT JOIN and a CTE (both are not allowed in an index view)

> ```
>     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Example
>     CREATE TABLE Example (
>       Id INT primary key,
>       Entity varchar(50),
>       Parent varchar(50)
>     )
>     
>     
>     INSERT INTO Example
>     VALUES 
>        (1, 'A', NULL)
>       ,(2, 'AA',  'A')
>       ,(3, 'AB','A')
>       ,(4, 'ABA', 'AB')
>       ,(5, 'ABB', 'AB')
>       ,(6, 'AAA', 'AA')
>       ,(7, 'AAB', 'AA')
>       ,(8, 'AAC', 'AA')
>     
>     
>     
>     SELECT *
>     FROM Example
>     
>     ;WITH CTE AS (
>      SELECT Parent, COUNT(*) as Count
>       FROM dbo.Example
>       GROUP BY Parent
>     )
>       
>     SELECT e.Entity, COALESCE(Count,0) Count
>     FROM dbo.Example e
>     LEFT JOIN CTE g
>     ON e.Entity = g.Parent
>
>
> GO
> ```

- [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2b666ff60e6d37c8bd3752611fd8a02)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that using a CTE neither a LEFT JOIN because there are many [restriction using the indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017).

## Workaround

I suggest splitting the query into two part:

1. Create an indexed view instead of a common table expression (CTE)
2. Create a non indexed view that perform the LEFT JOIN

Beside that, create a Non-Clustered index on `Entity` column in Table `Example` .

Then when you query the non-indexed view, it will use indexes

```
--CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE Example (
  Id INT primary key,
  Entity varchar(50),
  Parent varchar(50)
)

--INSERT VALUES
INSERT INTO Example
VALUES 
   (1, 'A', NULL)
  ,(2, 'AA',  'A')
  ,(3, 'AB','A')
  ,(4, 'ABA', 'AB')
  ,(5, 'ABB', 'AB')
  ,(6, 'AAA', 'AA')
  ,(7, 'AAB', 'AA')
  ,(8, 'AAC', 'AA')

--CREATE NON CLUSTERED INDEX
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx1 ON dbo.Example(Entity);

--CREATE Indexed View

CREATE VIEW dbo.ExampleView_1
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS 
 SELECT Parent, COUNT_BIG(*) as Count
  FROM dbo.Example
  GROUP BY Parent

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.ExampleView_1(Parent);

--Create non-indexed view
CREATE VIEW dbo.ExampleView_2
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS 
    SELECT e.Entity, COALESCE(Count,0) Count
    FROM dbo.Example e
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ExampleView_1 g
    ON e.Entity = g.Parent
```

So when you perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExampleView_2 WHERE Entity = 'A'
```

You can see that the view  Clustered index and the Table Non-Clustered index are used in the execution plan:

[image]

## Additional Information

I didn't find additional workarounds to replace the use of `LEFT JOIN` or `UNION` or `CTE` in indexed views, you can check many similar Stackoverflow questions:

- [Indexing views with a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646612/indexing-views-with-a-cte)
- [What to replace left join in a view so i can have an indexed view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476933/what-to-replace-left-join-in-a-view-so-i-can-have-an-indexed-view)
- [Create an index on SQL view with UNION operators? Will it really improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751838/create-an-index-on-sql-view-with-union-operators-will-it-really-improve-perform)

---

## Update 1 - Splitting view vs. Cartesian join

To identify the better approach, i tried to compare both suggested approaches.

```
--The other approach (cartesian join)
CREATE TABLE TwoRows (
    N INT primary key
)

INSERT INTO TwoRows
VALUES (1),(2)

CREATE VIEW dbo.indexedView  WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT 
        IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent) as Entity
        , COUNT_BIG(*) as CountPlusOne
        , COUNT_BIG(ALL IIF(T.N = 2, NULL, 1)) as Count
    FROM dbo.Example E1
    INNER JOIN dbo.TwoRows T
        ON 1=1
    WHERE IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX testIndex ON indexedView(Entity)
```

I created each indexed view on seperate databases and performed the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM View WHERE Entity = 'AA'
```

**Splitting view**

[image]

**Cartesian Join**

[image]

**Time Statistics**

*The time statistics shows that the Cartesian join approach execution time is higher than the Splitting view approach, as shown in the image below (cartesian join to the right):*

[image]

**Adding WITH(NOEXPAND)**

Also i tried to add `WITH(NOEXPAND)` option the the cartesian join approach, to force the database engine to use the indexed view clustered index and the result was as following:

[image]

I cleared all caches and perform a comparison, the Time statistics comparison shows that the Splitting view approach is still faster than the cartesian join approach *(`WITH(NOEXPAND)` approach to the right)*:

[image]

Comment: Yes - getting the clustered index onto Parent will definitely be an improvement performance-wise...and agree this is more straightforward that the OP's solution.

Comment: While my cartesian join fit my original use-case a little better ultimately I have to agree this is the favored and less-hacky solution to this problem. Thanks for the comparison for performance.

Comment: Is there any difference in the execution plan when you use `IIF` instead of `CASE WHEN`?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish what I was after by doing a **cartesian join** on the rows which would be 0 count (N=2).

Create table called two rows which will duplicate the grandchildren

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TwoRows
CREATE TABLE TwoRows (
    N INT primary key
)

INSERT INTO TwoRows
VALUES (1),(2)
```

Get the original table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Example
CREATE TABLE Example (
    Id INT primary key,
    Entity varchar(50),
    Parent varchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO Example
VALUES 
     (1, 'A', NULL)
    ,(2, 'AA',  'A')
    ,(3, 'AB','A')
    ,(4, 'ABA', 'AB')
    ,(5, 'ABB', 'AB')
    ,(6, 'AAA', 'AA')
    ,(7, 'AAB', 'AA')
    ,(8, 'AAC', 'AA')
```

Create the indexed view

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.indexedView 
CREATE VIEW dbo.indexedView  WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT 
        IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent) as Entity
        , COUNT_BIG(*) as CountPlusOne
        , COUNT_BIG(ALL IIF(T.N = 2, NULL, 1)) as Count
    FROM dbo.Example E1
    INNER JOIN dbo.TwoRows T
        ON 1=1
    WHERE IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY IIF(T.N = 2, Entity, Parent)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX testIndex ON indexedView(Entity)

SELECT *
FROM indexedView
```

I wasn't able how to avoid using `COUNT_BIG(*)`

Comment: I don't think it is performant when handling huge tables. I suggest trying both approaches and compare performance.

Comment: Also change `ON indexedView(Parent)` to `ON indexedView(Entity)` since there is no column called parent in the view

Comment: Thanks, yeah I changed Parent to Entity in an edit and forgot to change the index. I will test it out

Comment: I think it'll run fine...the cost will be absorbed on insert/update/delete as with a trigger.

Comment: @Parox it is better to split the view into 2 views as mentioned in the other answer, also take a look at the references provided in the answer, you will see that this approach is used by other experts

Comment: @Clay comparing to the trigger approach, this approach is definitely better, but have you check the other answer approach? it is more straight.

Comment: @Parox if you are looking to achieve better logic than the other approach is better, i don't know what is the benefit of using this approach. I upvoted the question since it is an interesting topic, but i didn't upvote this answer because i don't find it a good way to replace `CTE` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @ParoX i tried to do a comparison between both approaches, check my answer update

Answer (score 0):

You can create `AFTER INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE` [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on your `example` table and a new table to materialized the results.

In the trigger, you are allowed to use any statement. You can do this in two ways, depending on how fast is your query initial query.

For example, you can truncate the table on every `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` and then to calculate the count and insert it again (if the query is fast).

Or you can rely on `inserted` and `deleted` tables which are special tables visible in the trigger context and showing how rows values have changed.

For example, if a record exists in the `inserted` table and not in the `deleted` - this is(are) a new row(s). You can calculate the `COUNT` only for them.

If a record exists only in the `deleted` table - this is a deletion (we need to remove the row for our precalculated table).

And a row exists in both tables - these is an update - we need to perform new count for the record.

One thing is very important here - do not manipulate the rows one by one. Always work in batches of rows for the three cases above or you will end up with poor performing trigger which will delay the CRUD operations with the original table.

Comment: Great suggestion and definitely acts the same as an indexed view but with more upfront cost of getting everything just right, however i understand that at the end of the day they both have similar impact and management required internally I'd still like to solution to use a normal indexed (materialized) view over a materialized table